# When should we expect atmospheric info from the most promising planets for life, Trappist-1e?

Tags: james-webb-space-telescope, habitable-zone, trappist-1

It seems like other exoplanets in the Trappist-1 system have been studied by JWST but perhaps most promising planet for life, [Trappist-1e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1e), has yet to get studied or at least have any published news.

Is there any particular reason(s) 1e hasn't gotten studied, and is there any exact time we could expect a transit to be observed so we can get some information on the planet's atmosphere?

I understand position of JWST, orbital mechanics of Trappist-1, and competing projects all contribute to the answer but 1e seemed like something that would be prioritized over the other exoplanets in the system.

Comment: No, 1b and 1c have been prioritized - stronger transit signals. 1e is queued up.

Comment: In other words, it's easier to get transit data from 1b & 1c so they preferred those targets?

Comment: Both transit and eclipse signals are stronger for closer-in planets - it is eclipse mapping that has been recently used to argue both 1b and 1c are bare rocks (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06232-z).